# copying objects with data fields

Tags: java

I need to copy all content of class object to new class object. I don't need to copy references to data, because in that case if I change fields in object a2 those data will be changed in object a2.

```
public class Msg {
    String info="";
    HashMap fld = new HashMap();

    public void assign(Msg value) {
        info = value.infol;
        fld = value.fld;
    }

}

// Do stuff with class
a1 = new Msg();
a1.info="111";
a1.fld.put("1","111");

a2 = new Msg();
a2.assign(a1);
```

How to realise function `assign`?

Comment: do you need a shallow copy or a deep one ?

Comment: Please respect [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). It helps other understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a copy of your `HashMap` as well or you will have 2 objects pointing to the same `HashMap`.

```
public void Assign(Msg value)
{
    Info = value.Infol;
    fld = new HashMap(value.fld);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties( dest, source );
```